# Android studio not showing connected devices

Tags: android, android-studio

my android studio is not showing virtual devices upon running a project including my usb connected android phone and Genymotion virtual devices. I have tried Android studio versions 3.3 , 2.3 and 3.1 but still facing problem. i have installed genymotion plugin and all sdk tools but still its showing "No connected devices". Please help

Comment: It might be a problem with ADB. Try deleting the platform-tools in the SDK and reinstalling it. It might help

Answer (score 1):

It can either be an adb problem or a driver problem (for Samsung devices you have to install drivers).

You also have to set your devices in Developer mode and have USB debugging enabled on them.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have the required drivers. Just search for the ADB drivers of your PC. If you have the Offline Drivers bundle just run it.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually add genymotion devices to android studio using below command from terminal

```
adb connect 192.168.74.101:5555
```

Change the IP of your device as you've got in the genymotion device title
[image]

if successful, it returns:

```
connected to 192.168.74.101:5555
```